# itext pdf2data web application not start

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, itext, pdf2data

Did anyone try the pdf2data web application come with 2.0.1, it's a lightweight template editor web application.

I was testing the pdf2data 2.0.1 web application,  but I get error, the web application cannot start, this is the error message I got from Tomcat log:

15-Mar-2018 20:03:29.526 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
15-Mar-2018 20:03:29.529 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/pdf2data] startup failed due to previous errors

I followed this installation guide: https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Web%20application%20installation%20guide%20pdf2Data.pdf

The pdf2data war file I used is: 2.0.1
Tomcat 8.5,   JDK 1.8

James

Comment: I have asked the pdf2data experts at iText Software to take a look at your question. Are you by any chance a customer with a support contract? In that case it is better to contact iText Software directly, because pdf2data is a brand new product, and I don't expect that the Stack Overflow community already has a lot of knowledge about it.

Comment: After open some debug information in tomcat by creating logging.properties under /WEB-INF/classes folder,   I figured out it's a configuration issue,  the web application is working now.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: What was the issue? For the next person who comes along.

Comment: pdf2data web application need looking for a license file when start, in web.properties, (licensekey=xxxxxxx)  I pointed to wrong folder.